# What are the differences between string literal and const string literal

Tags: c, declaration, c-strings, string-literals

What is difference between two definitions below:

```
    char *str1 = "string 1"; // (1)
    const char *str2 = "string 2"; // (2)
```

(1), is this an undefined behavior for string literal ?

If no, what is definition we should use (can you give me some examples) ?

Comment: Answers differ between C/ C++.  In C both are OK.

Comment: i would like to know the answer both in C and  C++

Comment: The _string literal_ is the same in both lines of code as the _string literal_ is just the `"string x"` part

Comment: 1 is invalid in modern C++, although you might find some compilers accept it with a warning.

Comment: it's not duplicate. And i updated the question

Comment: Please ask two questions – one for C, one for C++.  Dealing with both in a single answer is messy. Note that `strcpy(str1, "abc");` yields no warning but does invoke undefined behaviour; you're attempting to modify a string literal (and you're not allowed to do that), and doing so usually ends with a crash at run-time. The compiler does not have to identify undefined behaviour. The second `strcpy(str2, "abc")` fails to compile because you're attempting to modify data via a pointer that you've said points to constant data — that's not allowed either, and the compiler is required to report that.

Comment: Sorry about mixing two languages. I deleted the c++ tag.

Comment: Hitokiri, you think there are 2 things here: string literal and const string literal.  There are 3: 1) _string literals_ "string 1" and "string 2" 2)  a pointer `char *str1` and 3) a pointer `const char *str2`. Compiler raises the warning just for `strcpy(str2,"abc");` because code passed a `const char *` to a `char *` of `strcpy(char *, ...`.  The warning  is nothing about _string literals_.

Comment: Thank you so much, i deleted the strcpy because i want to focus on the string literal. Thank to your comments, i understand the warning in strcpy function.

Comment: The strcpy is just one example to prove 2 defintions are different, but thank to your answer, i think it’s bad example. Sorry for my fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a mutable string you should use the following

```
char str1[]="string 1";
```

In C++ you cannot convert a string literal to non-const, in C you can, but this practice is not recommended.

Update.

In C++ you may do the following

```
char *str1 = (char *)"string 1" ; // (1)
```

But you must not use this pointer to change the value of the string.

Comment: Thanks. But i do not ask about mutable string.

Comment: In C a string literal is *already* non-const, although you are still not allowed to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

> (1), is this an undefined behavior for string literal ?

This declaration

```
char *str1 = "string 1"; // (1)
```

is a valid declaration of a pointer to a string literal in C. Opposite to C++ in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays.

However string literals are immutable in C as in C++. You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

It is preferable to declare pointers to string literals as it is required in C++ that is like

```
const char *str2 = "string 2"; // (2)
```

This makes your program more safer because the compiler will issue an error if you will try to pass a pointer to a string literal to a function the corresponding parameter of which is a pointer to non-constant char.